# OAUTH2gLogging user out of their session Django

Tags: python, django, google-calendar-api, oauth-2.0

I am using the OAUTH API to verify access to the users google calendar. They are not logging into my system using OAUTH, just accepting my site accessing their data.

The problem is, if the user is logged out of their google account and after they hit verify, it force logs them out of their session and I have no way of linking them back up.

This DOES work if they are already logged into the google account in their browser session and hit accept, they will be redirected to the right page.

I replicate the error when the cache, cookies are clear and they need to relogin into their google account to verify.

I've tried storing the session ID, etc, but the request parameter is not containing the same request data as the initial view, so there is a conflict in the data I am trying to retrieve.

The user is logged in using the standard Django libraries for the credentials model.

## CODE

```
FLOW = flow_from_clientsecrets(
    CLIENT_SECRETS,
    scope='https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.readonly',
    redirect_uri='http://127.0.0.1:8000/oauth2callback')
```

---

'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
Main function dealing with auth verification
'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''

```
def index(request):
  current_user = User.objects.get(username=request.user.username)
  storage = Storage(CredentialsModel, 'id', current_user, 'credential')
  credential = storage.get()
  if credential is None or credential.invalid == True:
    FLOW.params['state'] = xsrfutil.generate_token(settings.SECRET_KEY,
                                                   request.user.id)
    authorize_url = FLOW.step1_get_authorize_url()
    return redirect(authorize_url)
```

---

'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
User then calls the data function once authenticated
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''

```
def auth_return(request):

    print("THE CURRENTLY REQUESTED USER IN THIS SESSION REQUEST IS %s"%(request.user.username))

    credential = FLOW.step2_exchange(request.REQUEST)
    try:
      current_user = User.objects.get(id=request.user.id)
    except:
        return HttpResponseRedirect("/login")

    storage = Storage(CredentialsModel, 'id', current_user, 'credential')
    storage.put(credential)
    return HttpResponseRedirect("/get_cal")
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so this was a bit more involved than I thought.

I fixed this by adding a state parameter of the currently logged in username.

```
logged_in_username = request.user.username
user_data = {'var_test' : logged_in_username}
pass_param = urllib.urlencode(user_data)
FLOW.params['state']=pass_param
authorize_url = FLOW.step1_get_authorize_url()
```

This gave me the ability to query the user from the DB via the User model in Django contrib. I parsed out the state var from the URL:

```
#Get the currently logged in username
user_variable_data = str(FLOW.params['state'])

#get rid of the var_test= preprended text data for parsing reasons
user_variable_data = user_variable_data[9:]

#Get that user from the database in the form of a user object
current_user = User.objects.get(username=user_variable_data)
```

and then built a custom backend authentication file to auth the user without a password to maintain the request like nothing weird ever even happened.

```
user = authenticate(username=user_variable_data)
login(request, user)
print("AUTHENTICATED")
```

## Appended this to settings file

```
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
    'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',
    'procrastinate.auth_backend.PasswordlessAuthBackend',
)
```

## Custom Backend File

from django.contrib.auth.backends import ModelBackend
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class PasswordlessAuthBackend(ModelBackend):
    """Log in to Django without providing a password.

```
"""
def authenticate(self, username=None):
    try:
        return User.objects.get(username=username)
    except User.DoesNotExist:
        return None

def get_user(self, user_id):
    try:
        return User.objects.get(pk=user_id)
    except User.DoesNotExist:
        return None
```